# MySQL diacritic insensitive search (Arabic)

Tags: mysql, arabic, diacritics

I have trouble making a diacritic insensitive search with arabic text.

I have tested multiple setups for the table in question: encodings in utf8 and utf16 as well as collations in utf8_general_ci, utf16_general_ci and utf16_unicode_ci.

The search works for åä special characters. I.e:

```
select * from test where text like '%a%'
```

Would return columns where text is a, å or ä. But it won't work with the Arabic diacritics. I.e if the text is بِسْمِ and I search for بسم, I don't get any hits.

Any ideas how to get pass this?

The real usage will later be PHP (a search function), but I'm working directly in the MySQL db just for testing before I port it over to PHP.

(from Comment)

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    ↵ id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ↵ text text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    ↵ PRIMARY KEY (id)↵
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 2):

`SHOW COLLATIONS;` to see what collations you have available.  On my version, I don't see anything that looks tailored to Arabic.  However, `utf8_unicode_ci` seems to do the folding you want.  Here is a simple way to try it:

```
SELECT 'بِسْمِ' = 'بسم' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The result I got back was 1 (true), meaning they are considered equal.  With `utf8_general_ci` it came back with 0, meaning not equal.

Then declare your fields to be `VARCHAR(...) (or TEXT) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`;  Similarly for utf8mb4.

To build your own collation (and submit it for inclusion in future versions), see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-collation.html

Comment: I've set the character set to utf8 and collation to utf8_unicode_ci, still searching for **select * from test where text like '%بسم%**
Doesn't give any hits.

I do get back 1 on the test line you wrote **SELECT 'بِسْمِ' = 'بسم' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci**.

**SHOW COLLATIONS;** doesn't work (I get an error), but I can see in my MySQL GUI (SequelPro) that the char set and collation should have been set.

I've also tried searching like this: **select * from test where text like '%بسم%' collate utf8_unicode_ci** Without success.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table;` -- to make sure that the column in question says `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`.  `SHOW COLLATION;` (my typo)

Comment: **SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table;** got me this result:

**test CREATE TABLE `test` (↵  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,↵  `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,↵  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)↵) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci**

Comment: Try Collation `utf8_persion_ci`.

Answer (score 2):

(This is not an "answer", but a "resolution".)

It seems that `LIKE` does not work with your Arabic string.  I don't know how much more it fails on.  I recommend you write a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com .  Here is a test case that shows that neither `LIKE '...'` nor `LIKE '%...%'` finds both strings, whereas '=' works:

```
CREATE  TABLE so28863402 (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    txt text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,   -- deliberate choice of COLLATION
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO so28863402 (txt) VALUES
    (UNHEX('D8A8D990D8B3D992D985D990')),  -- Using hex to avoid any copy/paste issues
    (UNHEX('D8A8D8B3D985'));  -- The values should compare equal
SELECT id, txt, HEX(txt) FROM so28863402;
SELECT txt, COUNT(*) FROM so28863402 GROUP BY txt; -- GROUP BY finds them equal.
SELECT * from so28863402
    WHERE txt = 'بسم';   -- Finds both rows (correct)
SELECT * from so28863402
    WHERE txt LIKE '%بسم%';  -- Finds one row (incorrect)
-- Further checks:
SELECT * FROM so28863402 WHERE txt  =   UNHEX(  'D8A8D8B3D985'  );
SELECT * FROM so28863402 WHERE txt LIKE UNHEX(  'D8A8D8B3D985'  );
SELECT * FROM so28863402 WHERE txt LIKE UNHEX('25D8A8D8B3D98525'); -- x25 is '%'
```

Comment: Nice finding, we are almost there now! Using = instead of LIKE almost solved the case. But I still need something corresponding to %, to find words like **بسم الله** or **بِسْمِ الله** - there is no space between بسم and الله - its one word. Since the text column won't consist of only one word (بسم) but a complete sentence, so you won't find the word in the sentence without using something corresponding to %.

Comment: I'm glad you are getting somewhere.  Alas, I fear that may have to wait for a resolution to the bug report I suggested.  (I'm not in a position to work on such bugs.)  I do see a space in the middle of ' بِسْمِ الله':  SELECT HEX(' بِسْمِ الله') is 20D8A8D990D8B3D992D985D99020D8A7D984D984D987 .

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Rick, I've reported the bug, let's see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I solved the problem using these steps:

1. Create a function to remove the diacritic and unify the similar characters

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION AR_UNIFY(s VARCHAR(191) )
   RETURNS VARCHAR(191)
   DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN
       RETURN REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( s,'أ','ا'), 'ي','ى'), 'إ','ا'), 'ة','ه') ;
   END;
   ```
2. Use this function in the condition inside the SELECT statement like this:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE AR_UNIFY(name) LIKE AR_UNIFY("%أإا%");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table name
WHERE MATCH (name of column in MYSQL )
AGAINST ('بسم ' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This command ignore Diacritic. Try it.