# Search for "إ" char and return all words contains "ا" or "أ" or "إ" char?

Tags: php, mysql

In Arabic language there are some character the public people can may way for example character `ا` can be written by one of these `(أ,إ,ا)` and character `ه` can be written by one of these `(ه, ة)` and so on.

for more clarify: may user search the keyword `ايمان` I will return all results like `ايمان or أيمان or إيمان`, and if he search for `إيمان`  I will return also the same three words, and if he search for `أيمان` I will return also the same three words.

I want if user search of one of them `(أ,إ,ا)` return all words which contain any one of them

Comment: select * from table where term like '%pple%'

Comment: You'd have a dictionary stored in a table, then use the levenshtein distance to calculate similar words and add them to the search query.

Comment: I use Arabic language, may user search the keyword ايمان and I will return all results like ايمان or أيمان or إيمان -- is the question clear now?

Comment: @Sougata I update the question.

Comment: @Mauris I update the question.

Comment: @halfer I update the question.

Comment: @rene I update the question.

Comment: @Tiny Giant I update the question.

Comment: To all it is very common question in our website in Arabic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

first I replace all similar chars to one char in search keyword by php like this:

```
$keyword = str_replace('أ', 'ا', $keyword);
    $keyword = str_replace('إ', 'ا', $keyword);
    $keyword = str_replace('ى', 'ي', $keyword);
    $keyword = str_replace('ة', 'ه', $keyword);
```

then I replace column value stored in database in where sentence like this:

```
->whereRaw(" (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(page_title_ar, 'ة', 'ه'), 'أ', 'ا'), 'إ', 'ا'), 'ى', 'ي') like '%" . $keyword . "%' OR "
    . "REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(page_summery_ar, 'ة', 'ه'), 'أ', 'ا'), 'إ', 'ا'), 'ى', 'ي') like '%" . $keyword . "%' OR "
    . "REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(page_content_ar, 'ة', 'ه'), 'أ', 'ا'), 'إ', 'ا'), 'ى', 'ي') like '%" . $keyword . "%' OR "
    . "REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(page_title_en, 'ة', 'ه'), 'أ', 'ا'), 'إ', 'ا'), 'ى', 'ي') like '%" . $keyword . "%' OR "
    . "REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(page_summery_en, 'ة', 'ه'), 'أ', 'ا'), 'إ', 'ا'), 'ى', 'ي') like '%" . $keyword . "%' OR "
    . "REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(page_content_en, 'ة', 'ه'), 'أ', 'ا'), 'إ', 'ا'), 'ى', 'ي') like '%" . $keyword . "%'"
    . " ) and deleted <> 1")
```

and the problem

Answer (score 1):

try ORING

for example:
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE col like 'app%' or col like 'cpp%' or....
or 
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE col like '%app%' or col like '%cpp%' or....

Answer (score 1):

This post ([MySQL diacritic insensitive search (Arabic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863402/mysql-diacritic-insensitive-search-arabic)) covers searching Arabic-language text in a diacritic-insensitive way.  It seems that when you use the utf8_unicode_ci collation, بسم and بِسْمِ are considered equal.  But it is not so for the three words in your example.

I'm ignorant of Arabic, I am sorry.  Is it possible this is a bug in the collation? Is it possible another collation is required for Arabic in your situation?  In the meantime, you could compare substrings of your words if need be.